# Scipy.optimize.minimize function to determine multiple variables

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, lambda, scipy

I would like to find out optimal parameters like bo,ho,t1 and t2 such that the error function (f) is minimum (i.e., zero or close to zero). Full code is shown below,

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize as optimize

#OPTIMISATION USING SCIPY
def Obj_func(x):
    bo,ho,t1,t2=x
    f=-321226.4817 + (10400000*bo*ho**3 - 10400000*(bo - 2*t2)*(ho - 2*t1)**3)/(125 + (10400000*bo*ho**3 - 10400000*(bo - 2*t2)*(ho - 2*t1)**3)/(1563920*t1*(bo - 2*t2)))
    return f

initial_guess=[2,2,0.2,0.2]
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda bo,ho,t1,t2: (bo*ho - (bo - 2*t2)*(ho - 2*t1)-7.55)})
bnds = ((0, None), (0, None),(0, None), (0, None)) #all four variables are positive and greater than zero
#Always t1 and t2 should always be lesser than bo and ho
#res=optimize.minimize(Obj_func, method='SLSQP',initial_guess, bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
res=optimize.minimize(Obj_func,initial_guess, bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
print ("Result",res)
```

I am facing some issue here,
Q1. lambda function created for cons is giving me an error which states`"TypeError: () missing 3 required positional arguments: 'ho', 't1', and 't2'". Why this is happening? even though i followed the syntax correctly, some thing i am missing.
Q2. I need to minimize the objective function i.e., here its minimizing the error function (f) to zero or close to zero. I have mentioned optimize.minimize() without mentioning the type of optimization method. Is it ok? Will it give me the correct answer i am looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1 (syntax): Your constraint must take a single vector argument:

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize as optimize

#OPTIMISATION USING SCIPY
def Obj_func(x):
    bo,ho,t1,t2=x
    f=-321226.4817 + (10400000*bo*ho**3 - 10400000*(bo - 2*t2)*(ho - 2*t1)**3)/(125 + (10400000*bo*ho**3 - 10400000*(bo - 2*t2)*(ho - 2*t1)**3)/(1563920*t1*(bo - 2*t2)))
    return f

initial_guess=[2,2,0.2,0.2]
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda bhtt: (bhtt[0]*bhtt[1] - (bhtt[0] - 2*bhtt[3])*(bhtt[1] - 2*bhtt[2])-7.55)})
bnds = ((0, None), (0, None),(0, None), (0, None)) #all four variables are positive and greater than zero
#Always t1 and t2 should always be lesser than bo and ho
#res=optimize.minimize(Obj_func, method='SLSQP',initial_guess, bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
res=optimize.minimize(Obj_func,initial_guess, bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
print ("Result",res)
```

Output:

```
Result      fun: -15467.04696553346
     jac: array([  165915.125     ,   147480.57421875,  1243506.8828125 ,
        -130354.05859375])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 5
    njev: 1
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([ 2. ,  2. ,  0.2,  0.2])
```

Q2 (maths): The solver doesn't seem to like the problem as it is posed. I managed to get it spit out a solution by eliminating the equality constraint and one variable. The default solver still didn't work but `COBYLA` did:

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from operator import itemgetter

#OPTIMISATION USING SCIPY
def Obj_func_orig(x):
    bo,ho,t1,t2=x
    f=-321226.4817 + (10400000*bo*ho**3 - 10400000*(bo - 2*t2)*(ho - 2*t1)**3)/(125 + (10400000*bo*ho**3 - 10400000*(bo - 2*t2)*(ho - 2*t1)**3)/(1563920*t1*(bo - 2*t2)))
    return f

def Obj_func(x):
    bh, h, t = x
    btht = bh - 7.55
    D = bh*h*h - btht*(h-t)*(h-t)
    f = -321226.4817 + D / (125/10400000 + D*(h-t)/(781960*t*btht))
    return f

def cons(x):
    bh, h, t = x
    btht = bh - 7.55
    return (btht * h - bh * (h-t)) * (t-h)

def ge(i):
    return {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': itemgetter(i)}

initial_guess=[1,1,1]
initial_guess=[64,8,0.5]
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': cons}, {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': Obj_func}, ge(0), ge(1), ge(2))
res=optimize.minimize(lambda x: Obj_func(x)**2,initial_guess,constraints=cons,method='COBYLA')
print ("Result",res)
bh, h, t = res.x
bo, ho, t1, t2 = bh / h, h, t/2, (bh / h - (bh - 7.55) / (h-t))/2
print('bo, ho, t1, t2, f', bo, ho, t1, t2, Obj_func_orig([bo,ho,t1,t2]))
```

Answer with OP's initial guess:

```
# Result      fun: 285138.38958324661
#    maxcv: 0.0
#  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
#     nfev: 47
#   status: 1
#  success: True
#        x: array([  6.40732657e+01,   8.29209901e+00,   6.03312595e-02])
# bo, ho, t1, t2, f 7.72702612177 8.29209901408 0.0301656297535 0.430273240999 533.983510591
```

Please be advised that these are clearly local minima that depend on the initial guess. For example if I use `1,1,1` for the transformed variables:

```
# Result      fun: 5829.8452437661899
#    maxcv: 0.0
#  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
#     nfev: 48
#   status: 1
#  success: True
#        x: array([ 4.39911932,  0.93395108,  0.89739524])
# bo, ho, t1, t2, f 4.71022456896 0.933951079923 0.44869761948 45.4519279253 76.3534232616
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The objective function here is minimized below 0 i.e., fun: -15467.04696553346. But i would like to obtain the variables where the objective function is minimize to Zero, not below zero. How can i do this?

Comment: @PaulThomas Theoretically, it should be possible to use the objective function as an inequality constraint. But when I tried this it failed to find a solution. Sometimes a better initial guess can help. Would you be able to provide one that has at least a nonnegative function value?

Comment: Is it possible to limit the objective function (f) value close to zero if not exactly zero? or is it possible to take the absolute of f i.e., abs(f) in that case the minimum value will be zero or close to zero. Actually i am looking for a solution for these kind of functions which can have both positive and negative. I think a better initial guess would be [8, 8, 0.25, 0.25]

Comment: @PaulThomas I got it more or less to work but it is far from perfect. Have a look at the updated answer.